# How do I properly remove the integer portion of a double type value so that i only have the decimal portion remaining?

Tags: ms-access, double

I thought that this would be easy. I wanted to remove the Integer portion of all values in a field. For example if I have a field with Double data type containing a value of 17.0938 then I wanted to get a result of 0.0938. So I used MyField - INT(MyField). That should be 17.0938 - 17. The result ends up being 9.38000000000017E-02. What am I doing wrong?

Note: Some of these seem to be come out right, for example if MyField contains 8.1563 then the result ends up being 0.1563 as I would expect. The problem still exists though because I'm doing this so that I can join the data to another table that contains fractional increments and their decimal equivalents(0, 1/64, 1/32, 3/64, 1/16, 5/64, 3/32 all the way to 63/64). When I join the result of MyField - INT(MyField) to the column of the table that says 0.1563 is 5/32 the join doesn't find the row that has 0.1563 on it. So if a value of 17.0938 is in MyField then the result of MyField - INT(MyField) should be 0.0938 which would join to the row of the table with fractional equivalents that has 0.0938 in it so that I could return the column with the fraction (3/32). There is a bit more to it than that but trying to keep out any irrelevant explanation. I can give a full explanation if it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Use *CDec*:

```
Fraction = CDec(MyField) - Int(MyField)
```

However, do study my article on *extreme conversion of Imperial values*:

[Convert and format imperial distance (feet and inches) with high precision](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31931/Convert-and-format-imperial-distance-feet-and-inches-with-high-precision.html)

*(if you don't have an account, browse to the link: Read the full article)*

This will allow for conversions like:

```vb
SomeExpression = "4 ft. 5-7/64 in."
DecimalInches = ParseFeetInches(SomeExpression)
' DecimalInches -> 53.109375
```

and (note the precision):

```vb
' Meter/inch relation. 1 inch = 0.0254 m.
Const MetersPerInch As Currency = 0.0254

Inch = CDec(1) / MetersPerInch      ' Decimal.
Inch -> 39.370078740157480314960629921
Meter = MeterInch(Inch)
Meter -> 1.0
```

Full code is too much to list here. However, it can also be found on **GitHub**:

[VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round)

Comment: 1) Does CDec only work in VBA or something? I tried CDec(A.PO_Width) - Int(A.PO_Width) AS PO_Width_Decimal in my select statement but kept getting an error. If I run debug.print CDec(17.0938) - 17 in VBA it gives me exactly what I need. I can write the function for it I just wanted to have clarification.

Comment: 2) Do you know what it is doing? WHY wouldn't it work without CDec? Also, I have read to try to stay away from Decimal data type in Access and always use Double instead.

Comment: Yes, this is _very_ basic and caused by the nature and definition of _Double_ or _Float_. Search for "floating point errors" for a start. _Decimal_ is, in VBA, a sub data type of _Variant_ and is very different from _Double_, thus extremely useful for calculations, as long as these can be handled withing the range of _Decimal_ which - even though to be "large" for most people - is much more narrow than that of _Double_. Where to be cautious with _Decimal_ is when used as the _field data type_ for a table field. In VBA, however, it is often a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong your logic is fine, note that decimal notation,

```
0.0938
```

is equivalent to

```
 9.38000000000017E-02
```

The issues you have with the joins is due to the way data types are stored on Access, as an example `1/3` is a periodic number and is stored as `0.33333333`
Since a join does a *exact* comparison,  Access will not be able to match the fraction with the decimal value. One approach would be to convert the values from your equation and the stored factions results to string and truncate the results to a given number of characters (4 for example) before doing the join.